# Reselect redux with React hooks

Tags: reactjs

What is best practice to reuse old reselects with React hooks? I have read a bit on this page: https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks

This part:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { createSelector } from 'reselect'

const selectNumOfDoneTodos = createSelector(
  state => state.todos,
  todos => todos.filter(todo => todo.isDone).length
)
export const DoneTodosCounter = () => {
  const NumOfDoneTodos = useSelector(selectNumOfDoneTodos)
  return <div>{NumOfDoneTodos}</div>
}
export const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <span>Number of done todos:</span>
      <DoneTodosCounter />
    </>
  )
}
```

Could I just rewrite DoneTodosCounter like this:

```
export const DoneTodosCounter = () => {
  const NumOfDoneTodos = useSelector(selectNumOfDoneTodos)
  return NumOfDoneTodos
}
```

And reuse this snippet of code wherever I would have wanted to use `selectNumOfDoneTotos`? If not, how can I do this? What I suggest would just make me write more code...

Comment: The difference between your first and second examples is that in the first, you're returning JSX, whereas in the second, you're returning whatever `useSelector` returns; I can't remember the exact interface but I'm pretty sure it can't be used as a component in JSX

Comment: @OliverRadini if I import the last code snippet inside a component where I want to use this value, would not this work?